# IFS Returning N/A with VLOOKUP value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using an IFS formula to check for different conditions and produce a value:

```
=IFS(LEN(AP5)=0,"",AP5="N/A", "N/A", VLOOKUP(B5,'Calculation Date'!B:T,18, FALSE), "N/A", AVERAGE(AP5:AT5), AVERAGE(AP5:AT5))
```

The trouble I am having is with the third test around the VLOOKUP. When it's true, the formula works correctly. However, when the value returns false, I get an "#N/A" value in the cell.

If VLOOKUP is returning false, shouldn't it move onto my fourth test?

Comment: Add an iferror around the vlookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that the vlookup actually returns FALSE, and not #N/A (it should return FALSE only if this is the value in the lookup table) if the lookup value is missing from the lookup table, it would return #N/A, and the whole IFS function becomes #N/A.

Second, note that you are checking for NAs wrong. You should write:

```
=IFS(LEN(AP5)=0,"",isna(AP5), na(), vlookup...
```

Comment: Thank you, BoTz. I am actually looking for text on that second check related to AP5 (long story short, there is a macro that runs and converts certain data to "N/A" strings (not NA errors) based on the requirements of my sheet. I did run a separate check using just the VLOOKUP in a separate cell, and that returns FALSE. That's why I'm scratching my head - it works fine on its own, and works fine in the IFS when TRUE. If is FALSE, it works fine on its own, but throws an "#N/A" error when used in IFS.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working correctly. I had to add a "+0" to my lookup value in VLOOKUP. In other words

```
VLOOKUP(B5+0,'Calculation Date'!B:T,18, FALSE)
```